# Is the relation $fRg$ iff $\exists k > 0 \mid f(x) + k < g(x + k)$ on real functions transitive?

Tags: real-analysis, relations, elementary-functions

Is the relation on the set of real functions $fRg$ iff exists $k > 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) + k < g(x + k)$ transitive?

I have proved that it's not reflexive, not symmetric, not antisymmetric via counterexamples. All of these cases seemed to me tricky, and involved looking for some two functions with a particular relationship between their behaviour.
For instance, I proved that $R$ is not antisymmetric considering $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 2x + 2$.
However I stumble on looking for a counterexample for the transitivity. The relation seems to be formulated in such general terms though, that I can hardly imagine proving that it's transitive; intuition tells me that there must be some functions with particular local properties which refute transitivity.

Comment: Intuition is not reliable. Suppose $f R g$, witnessed by $k$, and $g R h$, witnessed by $m$. What about $f(x) + k + m$?

Comment: Hehe, thanks, that's beautiful how do those terms propagate via the applications of functions!